# Parameterized default route in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-router

How can i set default route with parameters (eg: www.test.com/landing-page?uid=123&mode=front&sid=de8d4)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing-page', pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: "landing-page", component: LandingPageComponent },  
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

My project has a workflow where user get redirected to my angular application via other website or application with data in query string. Is it possible to have default route with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you have just to add : plus your parameter in the path :

```
{ path: "landing-page/:uid/:mode/:sid", component: LandingPageComponent },
```

Comment: My query string will be in this specific format " ?uid=123&mode=front&sid=de8d4 "
rather than " landing-page/123/front/de8d4 "

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's Possible just change your route

```
      const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing-page', pathMatch: 'full' },

      { path: "landing-page, component: LandingPageComponent ,
        children:[
                   { path:':id',component: LandingPageComponent} ]
           },  
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
    ];
```

Import the ActivateRoute and Router module in your component and inject them in the constructor

```
contructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){ ... }
```

Subscribe the ActivateRoute to the ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);

    })
}
```

Comment: " ?uid=123&mode=front&sid=de8d4 " should be the format of the default query string(default route).

Comment: http://localhost:4200/dashboard?uid=123&mode=front&sid=de8d4
by using the same code you can access it

By mistake previously i added ActivateRoute in constructor  changed it to ActivatedRoute

Comment: No it doesn't work. When i enter " localhost:4200/dashboard?uid=123&mode=front&sid=de8d4 " manually in url  i get " localhost:4200/?uid=123&mode=front&sid=de8d4 " with nothing displayed.

Comment: Yes, By just default code for routes i was able to send query params. No need to add child routes.